# "ata[462]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdh': Invalid Argument" while installing Ubuntu 12.10 from DVD on Sabertooth Z77

Tags: boot, system-installation, raid

I am getting the error:

```
ata[462]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdh': Invalid Argument
```

I used the x64 Ubuntu 12.10 download burned to a DVD. I cannot boot from the DVD.

I am using:

- Sabertooth Z77
- Intel RAID Volume (256GB)
- 2x Intel SSD
- i7 3770
- 16GB DDR3

What are my options? Perhaps a different kernel? Better driver support?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to boot from USB
Just create a Live-USB with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)